# Unity3D - Upload a image from PC memory to WebGL app

Tags: unity, webgl

I need user to upload his(her) avatar picture from PC to game

How can I create a file dialog and upload a image to WebGL game?

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html

Comment: on sourceforge, tiny file dialogs has a function call for an open file dialog. it's a simple C C++ cross-platform file to add to your project.

Comment: Thanks Jon and Elisa. In other form gman helped me. check it out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183253/unity3d-upload-a-image-from-pc-memory-to-webgl-app/35201934#35201934